# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Students' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp.net mvc4 application, SQL Server 2012 database, EF & Linq by connect to database. I was changed in my database some tables from one schema to another, then give the following error, when to try to add new object into database:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Students' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I found the solution for this< is to set by code following lines:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Students ON

Insert Into Students(StudentId,StudentName) values(4, “TestName″)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Students OFF
```

But I dont know how can I do this by linq. My StudentId property is identity and auto increment. I didnt use .edmx and on the register method only context, smth like next:

```
Context.Students.Add(NewUser);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

I was try to add next line before StudentId but have no changes

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "StudentId", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
```

Does anybody have any ideas what I should to do, because I spent a lot of time and still didnt found an solution. Or does have any property for unbind the StudentId by Inserting from my context?

**Edit 1**

```
using (Context Context = new Context(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (Context.Students.Where(Usr => Usr.Username == username).Any())
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
                return null;
            }

            if (Context.Students.Where(Usr => Usr.Email == email).Any())
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
                return null;
            }

            Student NewUser = new Student
            {
                StudentId = null,
                Username = username,
                Password = HashedPassword,
                IsApproved = isApproved,
                Email = email,
                CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess = 0,
                LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                LastLockoutDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                IsLockedOut = false,
                LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            Context.Students.Add(NewUser);
            //Context.ExecuteStoreCommand
            Context.SaveChanges();
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
            return new MembershipUser(System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider.Name, NewUser.Username, NewUser.StudentId, NewUser.Email, null, null, NewUser.IsApproved, NewUser.IsLockedOut, NewUser.CreateDate.Value, NewUser.LastLoginDate.Value, NewUser.LastActivityDate.Value, NewUser.LastPasswordChangedDate.Value, NewUser.LastLockoutDate.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to manually insert/generate your primary keys?

Comment: Just a guess, but are you defining your "NewUser" object with an Id? If so that's the problem. As long as you leave your NewUser.StudentId = null (likely the default behaviour) it should "just work".

Comment: Yes, by default sendind 0, and i was tryed to set up null value, it give me an error, because in some part of code I need non-nullable values

Comment: @Tommy because I dont know how to fix my issue

Comment: @BorHunter - I guess I am saying I don't know what your issue is.  It looks like you want to create your own primary key and send that, but you have the database set to generate if for you (a good thing).  So, I am trying to determine why you need to send the primary key over on your own.  You should be able to (in LINQ), say `Context.Students.Add(New Student{StudentName = "Tommy"});` without having to send a primary key.

Comment: @Tommy my problem is following: everything work fine, until yesterday and i agree with you that send my own id is not right, but I dont see any another solution.

Comment: @cdlong I was try again to set up null property and have the following error: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.

Comment: show the code where you are creating the "NewUser" Object.

Comment: Have you tried removing the line "StudentId = null," completely?

Comment: I will fix this at least, just add in the model before StudentId [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] and save StudentId = null by code, thank you @cdlong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of trying to set the StudentId when you create your new entity.  You do not need to reference this during creation of the entity.

```
Student NewUser = new Student
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = HashedPassword,
                IsApproved = isApproved,
                Email = email,
                CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess = 0,
                LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                LastLockoutDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                IsLockedOut = false,
                LastPasswordFailureDate = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            Context.Students.Add(NewUser);
            //Context.ExecuteStoreCommand
            Context.SaveChanges();
```

If you need the Id of the newly created object, you can get that by asking for it **AFTER** you have called `Context.SaveChanges();`

```
Context.SaveChanges();
var newStudentId = NewUser.StudentId;
```

Comment: thank you, but in this case still sending a 0 property into database, but I fix the issue

Comment: @BorHunter How did you fix the issue?

Comment: @Asad - if you are using Code First, be sure you are applying the proper attributes to the PrimaryKey column.  If database first, be sure you have it set to an Identity column with AutoIncrement.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. I'm using Code First with Fluent API for configuration. For me at least, the problem turned out to be that autoincrement was enabled on a PK column that *wasn't* supposed to have autoincrement. I'm using a table per type inheritance hierarchy, and one of the derived classes used to be a standalone entity, so its PK was an identity column by default. Once it was added to a class hierarchy, I was supposed to remove this configuration, but forgot, hence the error.

Comment: @Asad I'm just comment UserId property inside my code where initialize my object and everything work well. But I'm using db first. Check your auto increment property.